# TicTacToe Telnet server in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, tic-tac-toe, networking

The code below works. The timings are as close as I can get to the system not packing out.

Basically telnet to a server to play tic-tac-toe. Automated it. Bottom left is 1, middle left is 2, middle right is 3 etc

Once a game is finished, I say "yes" and go again.

Anyway I can optimise it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from telnetlib import Telnet
import sys
from pprint import pprint
from random import randint

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 6666

tn = Telnet(HOST, PORT)
board=['','','','','','','','','']
winLines = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [2,4,6]]

def main():
   startup()
   while True:
      readBoard()
      selectMove()

   tn.close()


def startup():

   print tn.read_until("WordsWeNeverSee",0.1)   
   tn.write("O\n")          
   print tn.read_until("go first.", 0.1)       

def foobar():

   tn.write("yes\n")
   print tn.read_until("WordsWeNeverSee",0.1)  
   tn.write("O\n")  
   readBoard()

def readBoard():
   tIn = tn.read_until("WordsWeNeverSee",0.3)


   tLines = tIn.split('\n')  
   sys.stdout.write(tIn)
   tLines = tLines[::-1]
   if len(tLines)==13:
       row = tLines[3].replace(' ', '').split('|')
       #X|X|O
       board[0] = row[0]
       board[1] = row[1]
       board[2] = row[2]

       row = tLines[7].replace(' ', '').split('|')
       #X|X|O
       board[3] = row[0]
       board[4] = row[1]
       board[5] = row[2]

       row = tLines[11].replace(' ', '').split('|')
       #X|X|O
       board[6] = row[0]
       board[7] = row[1]
       board[8] = row[2]
   elif len(tLines)==14:
       row = tLines[3].replace(' ', '').split('|')
       #X|X|O
       board[0] = row[0]
       board[1] = row[1]
       board[2] = row[2]

       row = tLines[7].replace(' ', '').split('|')
       #X|X|O
       board[3] = row[0]
       board[4] = row[1]
       board[5] = row[2]

       row = tLines[11].replace(' ', '').split('|')
       #X|X|O
       board[6] = row[0]
       board[7] = row[1]
       board[8] = row[2]
   else:
      readBoard()

   if tIn.find("play again") != -1:
      foobar()


def countCharInCells(char, tup): # X, [2,4,6]
   count = 0
   for n in tup:
      if board[n] == char:
         count += 1

   return count

def findEmpty(tup): # [2,4,6]
   for n in tup:
      if board[n] == '':
         return n

   return -1

def selectMove():

   xCount = board.count('X') 

   # Strong first turn move
   if xCount == 0:
      tn.write('9')
      return

   # Best response to center start
   if board.count('X') == 1:
      if board[4] == 'X':
         tn.write('9')
         return

   # See if we can win
   for wl in winLines: #[[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [2,4,6]]
      if countCharInCells('O', wl) == 2:
         choice = findEmpty(wl)
         if choice != -1:
            tn.write(str(choice+1))
            return

   # Try to block opposition winning moves
   for wl in winLines:
      if countCharInCells('X', wl) == 2:
         choice = findEmpty(wl)
         if choice != -1:
            tn.write(str(choice+1))
            return

   # Try to snag a corner
   choice = findEmpty([0,2,6,8])
   if choice != -1:
      tn.write(str(choice+1))
      return

   # Pick a random valid square when stumped
   while True:
      choice = randint(0,8)
      if board[choice] == '':
         tn.write(str(choice+1))
         return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    main()
```

Comment: Did you intentionally call `main()` twice?

Answer (score 1):

I am not particularly a python expert but can offer some feedback from a fairly generic perspective.

- There are no useful (plain English) comments until line 105. There is definitely room to improve the commenting of this code.
- Unless StackExchange is affecting the formatting, this doesn't appear to adhere to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (the definitive Python style guide). For example, you are using three spaces per indentation level, not four.
- As @200_success spotted in a comment, you are calling `main()` twice at the end: is this intentional? I cannot understand why this would be.
- `foobar()` does not sound like a sensible name for a function: it gives me absolutely no clue as to what the function's purpose is.
- What is the significance of `"WordsWeNeverSee"`? This might be well documented in the Telnet library but it might be helpful to offer a brief explanation here, so somebody can follow this code without knowing that library well.  Failing that, at least a reference to the main documentation would be good.
- Your main game engine architecture smells funny to me. When `main()` first calls `readBoard()`, this can then lead to `readBoard()` being called recursively, and/or control passing to `foobar()` which then calls `readBoard()` again. This feels like it might lead to a deeply-nested call stack. Without following the logic through carefully I have no idea what the rationale is for this, but it seems unlikely to be the best design approach.
- Relatedly, your key functions `readBoard()` and `selectMove()` take no input and return no output. They are operating on data structures that exist globally, aside from their function scope - i.e. they are having side effects. This also seems unlikely to be the best approach; I'm not really qualified to say what the best or most-pythonic way might be, but a more object-oriented approach could be one way to go.
- `readBoard()` seems to have two blocks of identical code, inside the first `if` and following `elif`. In other words, you're saying: `if len(tLines)==13, then do some stuff; if len(tLines)==14, then do the same stuff; else do something different.`  Can you see the quick way to simplify this code?